# Profile confirmation email

Tags: profile, email, confirmation

Is it possible to have CiviCRM send an email confirmation to the submitter when civicrm/profile/create is used? And if not, what is the best work around? This is on a joomla site running CiviCRM 5.64.4

Context: We are using profile/create accept a request for materials. The materials are free. The profile includes a few contact fields (org name, email etc.) and fields from a custom data set.  It is common for folks to request materials more than once. The custom data set allows multiple records that are displayed "Tab with table". Dedupe checking is on and it works great to put each materials request on the tab for the appropriate organization.

We want to send a simple confirmation to the email that submitted the form, and there's no obvious way to do this.  Searching, I see several conversations about this as a good feature to add (like this one: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=6679.0.html) and even an old drupal module (https://github.com/emotive/CiviCRM-profile-notification).

Most current conversations seem to propose using the profile to add folks to a group and then turning on double opt in, but since people can make requests multiple times, they would already be in the group on the 2nd and subsequent request, so I'm thinking that would not work, but have not yet tested.

If this isn't possible, can someone recommend a better way to accomplish this goal?

(Also, note that we *are* receiving the confirmation to the emails we have indicated on the profile "Notify when profile form is submitted?", although that is not working quite right because the confirmation email shows the data from the FIRST materials request, not the one that was just added.  That's not a big deal since this is internal only and we can confirm the actual request on the tab.)

Comment: I've just realized that there's a bigger problem ... Not only does the email to our internal staff use the information from the original (rather than current) profile submission, that same incorrect information appears on the confirmation page shown to the submitting user.  So that's pretty clearly a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to try to confirm the "cached form data" problem on https://civicrm.org/de/demo. If everythings works you could utilize extension civirules for sending nicy html template mail confirmations.

Comment: I'm not sure if civirules has a rule to deal with when an existing contact adds to a multi-valued custom field, but it's worth exploring. Note you would also need the emailapi extension along with civirules in order to send email: https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api

Comment: AFAIK there's a "custom data on contact changed" trigger?